# Place a icon-button inside jQuery Mobile list divider

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I'd like to place an icon inside a list-divider, but it seems that jQuery Mobile lets me apply data-icons to normal list items only and not to list items with **`data-role='list-divider'`** assigned.

Simply enough, I want the list-divider to display an info button for providing the user with more information about this category, which should look like so:
[image: goal]

The point is, I'd like to place the info icon (with `data-icon='info'` or `class='ui-icon-info'`) within the list-divider, while maintaining consistency in the overall style, i.e.:

1. The category is headed by a list-divider, and not by a list-item that is just styled to look like the list divider.
2. The icon is displayed on the right side, like the arrows in the list items below. The icon has to have the same style of appearance like the arrows, which means that it should not look like a button or have an extra frame around it.
3. The list-divider, or at least the icon, should be clickable, so the user is able to get the information about this category.

I'd preferably like to achieve this **without any CSS customizations or JavaScript fiddling, using data-attributes only.**

This is what I got (using jQuery Mobile 1.3.2):

1. List-item with data-icon:

   `<li data-theme='a' data-icon='info'><a href='#' onclick='alert("Some info...");'>Category: A</a></li>`

   [image: Approach 1]

   Result:

   - Correct appearance of info-icon
   - Wrong appearance of category, because a normal list-item is used instead of a list-divider
2. Using a list-item with `data-role='list-divider'` assigned:

   `<li data-role='list-divider' data-icon='info'><a href='#' onclick='alert("Some info...");'>Category: A</a></li>`

   [image: Approach]

   Result:

   - No icon at all
   - Wrong title appearance and only text is hyperlinked instead of the whole list-item
3. List-divider with info-button inside:

   `<li data-role='list-divider'>Category: A<a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='info' data-mini='true' data-iconpos='notext' data-inline='true' data-theme='a' onclick='alert("Some info...");'>Category: A</a></li>`

   [image: Approach 3]

   Result:

   - Info button has wrong appearance

     - The button has a border which I like to remove for consistency, so the icon is shown in its usual disc appearance. Removing `data-role='button'` doesn't help, because the button wouldn't be rendered at all and would therefore not show the icon.
     - The icon's position is not on the right side. I know it would be possible using `data-iconpos='right'`, but I used this attribute for the icon-only (`notext`) layout already.
   - Category appearance is not pleasing, as the button increased its height. Even `data-mini='true'` didn't help.

I know there are a dozen of easy ways doing it the normal, less jQuery Mobile fixated way, but after 3 approaches, I'm eager to find out how this could be done with jQM.

Comment: is that what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/he3HK/

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Omar. Unfortunately, the user wouldn't be able to get information about the category, as your example doesn't contain a possibility to interact with the list-divider or the icon

Comment: oh, you need a button rather than an icon only.

Comment: Right! Sorry if I haven't pointed that out clearly enough.

Comment: This is the best I can do with `data-role="button"` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2PRv3/1/ Anyway, you can add more custom CSS to the icon in my previous comment to make it look like a button and bind events to it.

Comment: I know I'm nit-pick here, but with the button approach (I stumbled over it in my 3rd approach) the icon's appearance is altered and it doesn't look consistent to the arrows of the list items anymore. Also, extra CSS would be involved (okay admittedly, this wouldn't be an issue, I was just hoping to find a jQM native way in the first place), but foremost, it would be awesome to make the whole list-divider clickable and not just the button alone, which would then reflect the behavior of the clickable list items below. In any case, I really appreciate your effort! Thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

This works, including the click, i just test it

```
   <li data-role="list-divider">Test<div onclick='alert("Some info...");' class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="color:white;float:right"><div></li>
```

if the icon doesnt align with the rest of the icons add the below  to the style

```
   margin-right: -5px;
```

and change the pixels size to match the other icons